# sending ether Transaction failed when executing multiple transaction

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, infura

I am sending ether to an array of addresses. I am getting the nonce value from eth_getTransactionCount. But problem is that the first transaction is successful but for the rest of the transactions are not because the value of nonce is same as of first.

below is the code

```
 function signTransaction($t, $v, $d = '0x', $mt1 = "latest", $addr = '0x') {
    global $user_details;

    if($addr == '0x') {
        $user_address = $user_details['address'];
    } else {
        $user_address = $addr;
    }

    $dt = [$user_address, $mt1];
    $nonce = infuraReq('eth_getTransactionCount', $dt, 'bchexdec');

    $dt = [ 
        'nonce' => $nonce, 
        'from' => $user_address,
        'to' => $t,
        'amount' => $v,
        'data' => $d,
        'privkey' => privateKey()
    ];

    $rData = [
        'rawdata' => $dt,
        'signed' => web3Req('signtransaction', $dt, 'POST') 
    ];
    return $rData;
}
```

How do I solve this issue? Note: I cannot keep on changing the gas value as number of addresses are very high.

Comment: You can just increment the nonce for each transaction you send.

Comment: @smarx sir, already tried but not working

Comment: If you're having trouble, please share the version of your code that increases the nonce properly.

Comment: @smarx i just changed  "'nonce' => $nonce"  to "'nonce' => $nonce+1".. is it wrong?

Comment: Yes, that's wrong. That would still use the same (incorrect) nonce for each transaction.

Comment: @smarx then how to increase it?

Comment: For the first transaction, use the nonce you got from `eth_getTransactionCount`. On the second transaction, use that number plus one. On the third transaction, use that number plus two, etc.